# oauth facebook api access token misses tagged photos

Tags: facebook, oauth

When I fetch tagged photos for a user I only get a certain set even after requesting the friend_photos_videos/user_photos/user_photos_videos tags and basically any other permissions list.

However doing a sample call from the fb oauth overview site gives me the entire list of tagged photos for myself with their generated access token...how is this possible?

Just wondering if anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: How about sharing with us the code you are using?

Comment: Just share code block then only we will be able to solve your problem.